# Creating Dovecot Master users/passwords doesn't work

Tags: dovecot

I've been cracking my head on this for hours. I want to create a master user that has access to all dovecot accounts. I've followed the tutorial on [dovecot website](http://wiki.dovecot.org/Authentication/MasterUsers), however, it still it either says "Authentication failed" or "Waiting for authentication process to respond" and it never works. What could I possibly be doing wrong here? Thanks

//dovecot.conf

```
# 2.0.16: /usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE amd64  
auth_master_user_separator = *
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
namespace {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  prefix = INBOX.
  separator = .
  type = private
}

passdb {
  args = /usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
passdb {
  args = /usr/local/etc/dovecot/passwd.master
  driver = passwd-file
  master = yes
}
protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  client_limit = 6000
}
service imap {
  process_limit = 2048
  vsz_limit = 1256 M
}
service pop3 {
  process_limit = 2048
}

userdb {
  args = /usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
protocol pop3 {
  pop3_uidl_format = UID%u-%v
}
    --> as instructed from http://wiki.dovecot.org/Authentication/MasterUsers
```

cat passwd.master

```
master:{SHA}E9RIKlmYWisBS3ObR16GwKUZNZg=
```

telnet localhost 143

```
 Trying 127.0.0.1...
    Connected to localhost.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    a login loginuser*master mypassword
    * OK Waiting for authentication process to respond..
    * OK Waiting for authentication process to respond..                                                                                                                   
    * BYE Disconnected for inactivity.                                                                                                                                     
    Connection closed by foreign host.
```

or

```
telnet localhost 143                                                                                                         
Trying 127.0.0.1...                                                                                                                                                    
Connected to localhost.                                                                                                                                                
Escape character is '^]'.                                                                                                                                              
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN                                                
1 login loginuser*master mypassword                                                                                                                      
1 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.                                                                                                                     
* BYE Disconnected for inactivity.                                                                                                                                     
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

//dovecot -n

```
# 2.0.16: /usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: FreeBSD 8.2-RELEASE amd64  
auth_master_user_separator = *
disable_plaintext_auth = no
login_greeting = CFI mail server ready.
mail_location = maildir:~/Maildir
namespace {
  inbox = yes
  location = 
  prefix = INBOX.
  separator = .
  type = private
}

passdb {
  args = /usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
passdb {
  args = /usr/local/etc/dovecot/passwd.master
  driver = passwd-file
  master = yes
}
protocols = imap pop3
service auth {
  client_limit = 6000
}
service imap {
  process_limit = 2048
  vsz_limit = 1256 M
}
service pop3 {
  process_limit = 2048
}

userdb {
  args = /usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot-sql.conf
  driver = sql
}
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
protocol pop3 {
  pop3_uidl_format = UID%u-%v
}
```

Comment: From the "testing" section in the in the manual you linked to: *"If you had any problems, set `auth_debug=yes` and look at the logs."*

Comment: @HBruijn with auth_debug=yes set, it says "dovecot: auth: plain(?,127.0.0.1): Username character disallowed by auth_username_chars: 0x2a (username: loginuser*master) ". apparently 0x2a is a space character, but I don't have a space character in my username.

Comment: 0x2a is the asterisk  `*` not a space. - It might be that the check against the list of allowed input in the username parser is performed before the asterisk `*` is recognised as the auth_master_user_separator. Either select an alternative character, or add it to the `auth_username_chars` setting.

Comment: @HBruijn isn't the option "auth_master_user_separator = *" supposed to do  just that? Anyway i added auth_username_chars = * and it still gives the same error

Answer (score 4):

Finally got it work! First, I had to `auth_master_user_separator = +` instead of with `*`. This removed the complaint from dovecot that Username character disallowed by `auth_username_chars: 0x2a (username: loginuser*master)`

Then realized I was adding master password records using the htpasswd command to the wrong file `/usr/local/etc/dovecot/dovecot.master` yet in my configs it the right file is `/usr/local/etc/dovecot/passwd.master`. I don’t know how i failed to see that quickly.

Lastly I wasn’t testing the master user logins well using telnet. I was using `1 login loginuser+master mypassword` instead of `1 login existing_user@example.com+master mypassword`

Lastly my configs in dovecot.conf look something like

```
auth_master_user_separator = +                                                                                                                            
#auth_username_chars = *  #dovecot complains about the “*” character                                                                                                                               
auth_verbose = yes                                                                                                                                             
auth_debug = yes                                                                                                                                               
auth_debug_passwords = yes                                                                                                                                     
passdb {                                                                                                                                                       
        driver = passwd-file                                                                                                                                   
        args = /usr/local/etc/dovecot/passwd.master                                                                                                            
        master = yes                                                                                                                                           
        #pass = yes                                                                                                                                            

}                                                                                                                                                              
passdb {                                                                                                                                          
        #driver = shadow                                                                                                                                       
        driver = pam                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                                              
userdb {                                                                                                                                                       
  driver = passwd                                                                                                                                              
}
```